# R Heatmap - Change Axes to Variable From Function

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I'm trying to create a function in R that will take in two names (characters) and two doubles. It will then output a ggplot2 heatmap. Here's the data:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(`0` = c(0.0608, 0.0791, 0.0514, 0.0223, 0.0072, 
0.0019, 4e-04, 1e-04, 0, 0, 0), `1` = c(0.0912, 0.1186, 0.0771, 
0.0334, 0.0109, 0.0028, 6e-04, 1e-04, 0, 0, 0), `2` = c(0.0684, 
0.0889, 0.0578, 0.025, 0.0081, 0.0021, 5e-04, 1e-04, 0, 0, 0), 
    `3` = c(0.0342, 0.0445, 0.0289, 0.0125, 0.0041, 0.0011, 2e-04, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), `4` = c(0.0128, 0.0167, 0.0108, 0.0047, 0.0015, 
    4e-04, 1e-04, 0, 0, 0, 0), `5` = c(0.0038, 0.005, 0.0033, 
    0.0014, 5e-04, 1e-04, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `6` = c(0.001, 0.0013, 
    8e-04, 4e-04, 1e-04, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `7` = c(2e-04, 3e-04, 
    2e-04, 1e-04, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `8` = c(0, 1e-04, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `9` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0), `10+` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("0", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10+"))
```

Now if I hardcode the names on the axes (`homeScore` and `awayScore`) it works:

```
  df %>% 
    as_tibble(rownames = "awayScore") %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -awayScore, names_to = "homeScore", values_to = "probability") %>%
    mutate_at(vars(awayScore, homeScore), ~forcats::fct_relevel(.x, "10+", after = 10)) %>% 
    ggplot() + 
    geom_tile(aes(x=awayScore, y=homeScore, fill = probability)) +   
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "white", high = muted("blue"))+
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(2,2,2,2),"cm"))
```

This is the result:

[image]

But now, I want `homeScore` and `awayScore` to be variables in a function. So this is my new function with the same `df`:

```
TestFunction<-function(home,away){
  
  
  df %>% 
    as_tibble(rownames = away) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -away, names_to = "home", values_to = "probability") %>%
    mutate_at(vars(away, home), ~forcats::fct_relevel(.x, "10+", after = 10)) %>% 
    ggplot() + 
    geom_tile(aes(x=away, y=home, fill = probability)) +   
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "white", high = muted("blue"))+
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(2,2,2,2),"cm"))
  
}
```

But this plot is not what's expected:

[image]

What do I have to make the `homeScore` and `awayScore` on either axes become variables from a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use strings in `aes` instead of variables names of the dataframe you need to use the function `aes_string` instead.

Here is your updated code:

```r
TestFunction<-function(home,away){
    df %>% 
    as_tibble(rownames = away) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -away, names_to = home, values_to = "probability") %>%
    mutate_at(vars(away, home), ~forcats::fct_relevel(.x, "10+", after = 10)) %>% 
    ggplot() + 
    geom_tile(aes_string(x=away, y=home, fill = "probability")) +   
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "red", mid = "white", high = muted("blue"))+
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(2,2,2,2),"cm"))
  
}
TestFunction("homeScore",'awayScore')
```

Note that I changed the line `pivot_longer` to include `name_to=home` (you had it hardcoded) and also in the `aes_string` I put quotes in the `fill="probability`

Output:
[image]

Comment: Hey @Arault thanks for that, it seems to work apart from the fact that the strings can't have spaces. so `TestFunction("Manchester_City","Manchester_United")` works but not `TestFunction("Manchester City", "Manchester United")`

Comment: Yes indeed, in ggplot2 you cannot have variables with space. The only way to trick it would be to use ylabs & xlabs function on top of the variables names